# Which sports broadcast gets the highest TRP rate?

Tags: international-sports, media

Which sports broadcast is watched by **the most people** in the world, on television or online?

Indirectly, which sports match gets the highest TRP rate?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "TRP rate?" That's not a phrase I'm familiar with. (Also, how are you using the word "indirectly"?)

Comment: @pjmorse Thanks for comment, TRP = > Television Rating Point....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to article from [Whatculture](http://whatculture.com/sport/10-most-watched-sporting-events-in-tv-history?page=2) **FIFA World Cup** with average viewer 3.5 billion is the most watched sport broadcast in the world. But [**FIFA**](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=2015/m=12/news=2014-fifa-world-cuptm-reached-3-2-billion-viewers-one-billion-watched--2745519.html) says 3.2 billion and estimated 280 million people around the world watched matches online or on a mobile device.

And the *2014 World Cup final* between Germany and Argentina in Brazil was watched by more than **1 billion** viewers which suggest it might be the highest TRP match.